# type constructor currying? (trying to create a data constructor accepting one type from another data constructor accepting two types)

Tags: haskell, types, currying, dependent-type, type-constructor

I'm just starting to learn Haskell, and I'm trying to put it to practice by making a card game. I'm trying to create a type "Hand" which represents a fixed sized Vector of cards (using sized vectors as described here: https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/konn/prove-your-haskell-for-great-safety/dependent-types-in-haskell)

I've had a few attempts at this, but none of them have worked:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds, PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Type.Natural
import Data.Vector.Sized (Vector)
import Card -- | I have the Card type defined in another file

data Hand (n :: Nat) where
    Hand :: SNat n -> Vector Card n

{- fails with:
* Data constructor 'Hand' returns type 'Vector Card n'
    instead of an instance of its parent type 'Hand n'
* In the definition of data constructor 'Hand'
  In the data type declaration for 'Hand'
-}

type Hand = Vector Card

{- compiles, but it doesn't work as expected:
ghci> :k Hand
Hand :: *
(whereas I'd expect 'Hand :: Nat -> Vector Card Nat' or something)
-}
```

I'm not really sure what to call this, it seems something like type constructor currying to me, but maybe I'm completely wrong. I haven't been able to find something similar online. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5):

`Vector` from `Data.Vector.Sized` takes the size as the *first* argument, not the second, unlike in the linked tutorial.  So you need

```
type Hand n = Vector n Card
```

As for your GADT variant, you are simply missing the result type of the constructor.

```
data Hand (n :: Nat) where
    Hand :: SNat n -> Vector n Card -> Hand n
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

GADT constructor types always need a codomain of whatever type they are defining.  That said, I think the `SNat` here is unnecessary -- if the information of how many cards are in the hand comes from outside, there's no reason to hold onto it inside also.

Comment: thanks for the response! I'm still a little lost:

1. doesn't [`Vector`](https://github.com/konn/sized-vector/blob/master/Data/Vector/Sized.hs#L70-L72) take size as the second argument? maybe i'm looking at the wrong source

2. in the GADT variant, I thought it should be: `Hand` is a type constructor which takes a `Nat` and yields a type which is `Vector Card n`. in the one you supplied, I'm reading it as `Hand` is a type constructor which takes a `Nat`, and a `Vector` of `Card`s, and yields a type `Hand n`. I think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere...

Comment: or perhaps my intent isn't too clear: can I make a type constructor `Hand` which takes a type-level natural number `n`, and returns a `n`-sized `Vector` of `Card`s?

Comment: @zii, a constructor constructs the type being defined.  So the `Hand` constructor can only construct objects of type `Hand`.  You can make a *function* which takes a `SNat n` and returns a `Vector n Card`, say one that gives you `n` aces.  Is that what you meant?  What is your intended purpose of this constructor -- how would you use it?

Comment: @zii as for the order of the arguments, not sure what's going on there.  It's `Vector a n` in the one you linked, but the same package [on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-sized-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Sized.html) it's `Vector n a`.  Huh.

Comment: i think i just want a type `Hand n` which is the exact same type as `Vector Card n`. my thought process was: `Hand` takes a type `Nat` and gives me a type that's the same as `Vector Card n`, so I can write the `Hand` constructor with the GADT, but that's probably where I went wrong.